# Looping through chunked elements

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, foreach

I have 3 divs (`col-md-4`) and I have div blocks inside them. I am trying to get the elements by rows (as if the parent was one col-md-12 rather than their divided col-md-4s) but I couldn't figure out how to achieve it.

To clarify the issue (and simplify it), below I have added `data-order` attribute to show it's exact order and how I want them to be ordered.

**For preventing confusing, I have updated the question and added `data-id` attributes; imagine you don't have `data-order` attribute at all; I have only put it just to clarify the order.**

```
<div class="col-md-4 parent">
    <div class="child" data-id="3" data-order="1"></div>
    <div class="child" data-id="4" data-order="4"></div>
    <div class="child" data-id="8" data-order="7"></div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 parent">
    <div class="child" data-id="1" data-order="2"></div>
    <div class="child" data-id="2" data-order="5"></div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 parent">
    <div class="child" data-id="11" data-order="3"></div>
    <div class="child" data-id="7" data-order="6"></div>
</div>
```

How can I get the elements using a for loop (or foreach) to order those elements?

```
$('.parent').each(function(index) {
     console.log($(this).data('order')); // Using this gives 1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 3, 6
});

// However what I want to achieve is: when looped:
// console.log($(this).data('id'));    // "3, 1, 11, 4, 2, 7, 8"
```

What is the most suitable way to achieve this? How would you handle such case?

---

Like this:

```
 parent(1)-child(1)
 parent(2)-child(1)
 parent(3)-child(1)
 parent(X)-child(1)

 parent(1)-child(2)
 parent(2)-child(2)
 parent(3)-child(2)
 parent(X)-child(2)

 parent(1)-child(3)
 parent(2)-child(3)
 parent(3)-child(3) and so on...
```

Comment: In this example, I have put 3x `col-md-4` but can be more, however it won't matter; because what I am trying to achieve is: `parent(1)-child(1)`, `parent(2)-child(1)`, `parent(3)-child(1)` _[and when done looping the first children, start looping 2nds]_ `parent(1)-child(2)`, `parent(2)-child(2)`, `parent(3)-child(2)`, `parent(1)-child(3)`, `parent(2)-child(3)`, `parent(3)-child(3)`, etc - **Update:** I see what you mean, i forgot to add `</div>`s to children, fixed the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a loop that iterates over each `parent` until the collection is full:

```js
const collection = [];
const totalChildren = $('.child').length;
for (let i = 0; collection.length < totalChildren; i++) {
  $('.parent').each((_, parent) => {
    if (parent.children[i]) collection.push(parent.children[i]);
  });
}
console.log(collection);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 parent">
    <div class="child" data-order="1"></div>
    <div class="child" data-order="4"></div>
    <div class="child" data-order="7"></div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 parent">
    <div class="child" data-order="2"></div>
    <div class="child" data-order="5"></div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 parent">
    <div class="child" data-order="3"></div>
    <div class="child" data-order="6"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately you got me wrong :( Imagine you won't know the `data-order` attribute (I have put them just to clarify what I meant). I have updated the question. Imagine `data-order` doesn't exist at all and you need to order the elements in that order. I'd be grateful if you can update the answer, or delete it as it doesn't show what I asked

Comment: If `data-order` doesn't exist, what would determine how the elements are ordered in the collection? Or do you want the order to be hard-coded in the Javascript? Or do you want them ordered by `data-id` instead?

Comment: Like in my previous comment in OP: `parent(1)-child(1)`, `parent(2)-child(1)`, `parent(3)-child(1)` [and when done looping the first children, start looping 2nds] `parent(1)-child(2)`, `parent(2)-child(2)`, `parent(3)-child(2)`, `parent(1)-child(3)`, `parent(2)-child(3)`, `parent(3)-child(3)` and so on; and not explicitly 3 parents but more. _So in OP example: "3, 1, 11, 4, 2, 7, 8"_